# learning phrasal verbs

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I am preparing for CAE advanced, but I need to revise some aspects. By the way, I am filling in the right verb in use of english part 1.

This is the piece:

> But closer inspection reveals a milky surface covered in enamel dots, which ______ about two thirds of light.

The choice is between *put down, put out, cut down, cut out*.

Could you please give me some useful hints about the correct use of this kind of phrasal verbs? I can't sincerely figure out the right meaning of these verbs, moreover it happens that often these verbs have the same meaning.

Comment: All of the "compound verbs" *put down, put out, cut down, cut out* have multiple meanings, and covering the full range would be Too Broad for an answer here. As regards the specific "multiple-choice answer" test presented here, the expected answer is ***cut out***, which you could in principle have established from [this dictionary definition:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cut-out) *to stop something such as noise or light from reaching a place.*

Comment: They are not compound verbs, but (usually) verb+preposition, i.e. at word level they are two separate constituents. In, for example, "He finally backed down", "backed down", consists of a verb and a preposition without a complement. This is clearly the correct analysis since it's "backed" that takes the verbal inflections. There's no "back downed".

Comment: Do you have a problem with just *these* phrasal verbs or are you looking for advice on learning phrasal verbs in general? For a general question on learning phrasal verbs (i.e. *how* to learn them), you might try [Language Learning Stack Exchange](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi Jasper! Sorry for late answer, I am looking for learning phrasal verbs in a logical way...

Answer (score 2):

These phrasal verbs have a lot of meanings. The meanings that I have selected are applicable to the current context.

*Put down* means "to place on the floor [or a surface]", so it can't be that.

*Put out* means "to extinguish", so this is a possibility.

*Cut down* means "to reduce". However, this would imply that the enamel dots reduce only two thirds of the light, and not the remaining third, which seems to be over-complicated.

*Cut out* means "to eliminate", and this seems to be promising. The enamel dots *eliminate* two thirds of the light.

So, we have a choice between "put out" and "cut out". However, "put out" is normally used (in this context) to mean *extinguish* a light (like a candle).

So I would choose "cut out" as the most promising candidate.

Comment: There are plenty more meanings besides the few you've chosen to list here. For example, ***put down** = euthanise, write/record, demean/insult / etc., **put out** = inconvenience, etc.* I really think the range is too broad to be covered by a single answer here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right. I'll add that as a proviso.

Comment: Just a thought: If the enamel dots lit up, then the right choice would be "put out", but if they reduce light emitted from another source, then it would be "cut out."

Comment: @J.R. That would seem to be a little over-complicated for an English test.

Comment: It's actually what I thought the answer was at first. Moreover, I don't think that meaning of "put out" is any more complicated than the meaning of "cut out" being tested.